# Content Delivery Webservice Issue - System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero

Tags: content-delivery, odata, webservice

I've installing a fresh CMS using 2013 Sp1 Hr1.

CM is all up and running and i'm just putting together the content delivery webservice.  This is a separate website on my CD box and it's not linked to any website or XPM preview site etc.   I've taken the config files from the CD publication where configurations are working (i get content from the broker as expected etc)

I can hit my CD WS website like this:

http:cdweb/odata.svc and i get the page back from IIS

if I hit the page from URL/oData.svc/Publications (basically a simple query from the WS), I receive the following error:

```
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceHandledException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Handling an exception. Exception details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length
   at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
   at Tridion.ContentDelivery.Webservice.ODataService.ResourceRetrieval(String requestPath)
   at SyncInvokeResourceRetrieval(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</Description>
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

I'm using the Web.config configuration that is delivered with the installation package (path \Tridion 2013 SP1\Content Delivery\roles\webservice\dotNet\webapp\x86_64\webservice) as a sample, pasted below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                <!-- This section needs to be uncommented when using .NET 3.5
                    <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    -->
                <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                    <!-- These sections need to be uncommented when using .NET 3.5
                         <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
                         <section name="profilaeService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                         <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                         <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                         -->
                </sectionGroup>
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings/>
    <system.web>
        <!--
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
        -->
        <compilation debug="false">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
        <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
        <pages>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" />
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule" type="Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule" />
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
            </compiler>
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <!--
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules>
            <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
            <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
            <remove name="FileAuthorization" />
            <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule" type="Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule" />
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
            <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
            <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
            <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
            <remove name="WebDAV" />
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" appliesTo="v2.0.50727"><dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="webHttp">
                    <webHttp />
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <bindings>
            <webHttpBinding>
                <binding name="HttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152" maxBufferSize="2097152">
                    <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="81920" maxBytesPerRead="5120" maxDepth="32" maxNameTableCharCount="81920" maxStringContentLength="2097152" />
                    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
                <!-- In case of HTTPS support uncomment this block.
               <binding name="HttpsBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152" maxBufferSize="2097152">
                   <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="81920" maxBytesPerRead="5120" maxDepth="32" maxNameTableCharCount="81920" maxStringContentLength="2097152" />
                   <security mode="Transport">
                       <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                   </security>
               </binding>
                -->
            </webHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <!-- HTTP support -->
            <service name="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Webservice.ODataService">
                <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" bindingConfiguration="HttpBinding" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Webservice.IODataService" />
            </service>
            <service name="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Webservice.LinkingService">
                <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" bindingConfiguration="HttpBinding" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Webservice.Ilinking" />
            </service>
            <service name="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Webservice.AccessTokenService">
                <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" bindingConfiguration="HttpBinding" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Webservice.IOAuth2AccessToken" />
            </service>
            <!-- HTTPS support. Uncomment HttpsBinding configuration also.
            <service name="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Webservice.ODataService" >
                <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" bindingConfiguration="HttpsBinding" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Webservice.IODataService" />
            </service>
            <service name="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Webservice.LinkingService">
                <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" bindingConfiguration="HttpsBinding" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Webservice.Ilinking"/>
            </service>
            <service name="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Webservice.AccessTokenService">
                <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" bindingConfiguration="HttpsBinding" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Webservice.IOAuth2AccessToken" />
            </service>
            -->
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>

    <!--<system.diagnostics>
      <trace autoflush="true" />
      <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="All">
          <listeners>
            <add name="TraceListeners" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData= "C:\tridion\log\trace.svclog"/>
          </listeners>
        </source>
      </sources>
    </system.diagnostics>-->
</configuration>
```

Has anyone come across something similar to this?

I've rechecked the configs and followed the documentation found [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dcontent%2520delivery%2520webservice%26scope%3D%26min%3D10%26max%3D0%26sort%3D%26chunk%3D10&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1428696575668&currentQuery=content%2520delivery%2520webservice&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-89DF43CD-9B5A-4858-B830-B3D2BCAAB1BF&query=&scope=&filename=GUID-89DF43CD-9B5A-4858-B830-B3D2BCAAB1BF.xml&docid=GUID-89DF43CD-9B5A-4858-B830-B3D2BCAAB1BF&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=&toc=false)

Answer (score 4):

OK, annoyingly i found the issue.

If I call the url with

- http://URL/oData.svc/Pages it fails

...if I call it with

http://URL/odata.svc/Pages (basically a lowercase D in odata)

it works fine.

I'm now going to out into the streets and fight a man!

Comment: You must be using the Java version of the ODATA service...remember, NTFS is not case sensitive, but Tomcat on Windows is still Case Sensitive :P  ... not sure if it is your case....but I will not be the Man you were looking on the street to fight with :P

Comment: No this is on windows

Comment: you mean IIS or Windows with a Java based PWS?

Comment: i mean iis on windows, running as a .net website

Comment: That's weird....thanks for sharing John